# Free groups. Help me to understand this theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

This is the Theorem 2.9 from book Lyndon, Schupp "Combinatorial group theory".

Let $F$ - is free group, $G$ - is subgroup of $F$, $\forall g\in G$ define $G_g=Gp(\{h: h<g, h\in G\})$. So $A=\{g:g\in G, g\notin G_g\}$ is a basis of $G$.

I can't find mistake in the prove, but let $F=G=\mathbb{Z}_+$, then $G_g=G$ and $A$ is empty. So $A$ isn't basis.

What I do incorrectly?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. You've written an inequality $h<g$ for elements of $G$, but inequality is not generally defined in groups.

Comment: @LeeMosher, here used a lemma about every set can be orderify.

Comment: Even if, abstractly, any set can be ordered, to answer this question we have to know the precise definition of $<$ on $F$ and how it relates to the group operation.

Comment: They use the specific order defined on the bottom of page 6 of the book.

Comment: Lyndon and Schupp is an indispensable resource, but contains lots of errors. Magnus, Karrass and Solitar's book of the same name is an alternative reference for Chapter 1, and is a more "solid" reference (their Chapter 3 is relevant here). The neatest proof I know of the result here (Nielsen reduced bases exist for every subgroup) uses Stallings' foldings; see Section 6 of the paper *Stallings foldings and the subgroup structure of free groups* by Kapovich and Myasnikov [(arXiv)](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0202285)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which particular ordering is being used here, but in CGT there are a few different orders that are commonly used: length order (which simply says that $v\lt w$ iff $|v|\lt|w|$, given that the words are already reduced), shortlex order (which says that $v\lt w$ iff $|v|\lt|w|$ or $|v|=|w|$ and $v$ is lexicographically before $w$), or dictionary order (which is just full lexicographic order). For all of these, canon is to take the inverse of a generator as being after the generator itself in the lexicographic order. In the case of the one-generator free group (which is isomorphic to $\langle\mathbb{Z},+\rangle$ as you note, but which I think it's more helpful here to write explicitly using a generator, say $a$, so that $F=\{a^m\}, m\in\mathbb{Z}$), the definitions are *not* equivalent to the usual order on $\mathbb{Z}$. Instead, for the first two $a^m\lt a^n$ if $|m|\lt|n|$, or $|m|=|n|$ and $m\gt n$ (since as mentioned above we have $a\lt a^{-1}$). Written out explicitly, the order is $e\lt a\lt a^{-1}$ $\lt a^2\lt a^{-2}\lt\ldots$. Full lexicographic order is slightly more complicated than this, but the explicit version is that $e\lt a\lt a^2\lt\ldots$ $\lt a^{-1}\lt a^{-2}\lt\ldots$. Now, consider taking $g=a$, the generator. What's the set $\{h: h\lt g\}$, under any of these orderings? What is the group $G_g$? Is $g$ a member of this group?

Comment: Ok, I didn't see that there are this order. I thinked it can be all another.